# Custom CSS Bootstrap not operating as it should

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, animated

I came across this CSS menu which I intend to incorporate into a Bootstrap 3 system.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>
<style>

#transnav ul li {
background:#000;
list-style: none;
height: 44px;
float:left;
padding:10px 5px;
}

#transnav ul li a {
width: 150px;
height: 40px;
line-height: 53px;
border-bottom: 4px solid #636393;
padding:0px;
color: #fff;
font-size:24px;
font-weight:lighter;
text-align:center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

#transnav li:nth-child(1) a {
border-color: #636393;
}

#transnav li:nth-child(2) a {
border-color: #B5222D;
}

#transnav li:nth-child(3) a {
border-color: #D4953C;
}

#transnav li:nth-child(4) a {
border-color: #609491;
}

#transnav li:nth-child(5) a {
border-color: #87A248;
}

#transnav li:nth-child(6) a {
border-color: #ff0000;
}

#transnav li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #636393;
height: 9px;
}

#transnav li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #B5222D;
height: 9px;
}

#transnav li:nth-child(3) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #D4953C;
height: 9px;
}

#transnav li:nth-child(4) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #609491;
height: 9px;
}

#transnav li:nth-child(5) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #87A248;
height: 9px;
}

#transnav li:nth-child(6) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #ff0000;
height: 9px;
}


</style>
<body>
<div id="transnav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Coding</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Webmaster</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
```

This works as intended but when I use it in Bootstrap it operates differently. Here is my Bootstrap code:

```
style.css

.transnav {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 100px;
}
.transnav ul li {
background:#000;
list-style: none;
height: 44px;
float:left;
padding:10px 5px;
}
.transnav ul li a {
width: 150px;
height: 40px;
line-height: 53px;
border-bottom: 4px solid #636393;
padding:0px;
color: #fff;
font-size:24px;
font-weight:lighter;
text-align:center;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
-webkit-transition: .2s all linear;
-moz-transition: .2s all linear;
-o-transition: .2s all linear;
transition: .2s all linear;
}
.transnav li:nth-child(1) a {
border-color: #636393;
}
.transnav li:nth-child(2) a {
border-color: #B5222D;
}
.transnav li:nth-child(3) a {
border-color: #D4953C;
}
.transnav li:nth-child(4) a {
border-color: #609491;
}
.transnav li:nth-child(5) a {
border-color: #87A248;
}
.transnav li:nth-child(6) a {
border-color: #ff0000;
}
.transnav li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #636393;
height: 9px;
}
.transnav li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #B5222D;
height: 9px;
}
.transnav li:nth-child(3) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #D4953C;
height: 9px;
}
.transnav li:nth-child(4) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #609491;
height: 9px;
}
.transnav li:nth-child(5) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #87A248;
height: 9px;
}
.transnav li:nth-child(6) a:hover {
border-bottom: 35px solid #ff0000;
height: 9px;
}
```

Bootstrap page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
         <div class="container">
             <div class="transnav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Coding</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Webmaster</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
    <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem here?